# How to build a circle if...

Tags: geometry, circles

We have a point and two lines. Build a circle which has to pass through the point and has to be tangent to the given lines.

I appreciate any help and explanations!

Comment: The problem has no solution if, for example, the lines are parallel and one of them and the point are located on the same semiplane defined by the other line...something like $$\;\;. |\;\;|$$ so what are all the conditions given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the point and the circle centre $O$. Now we know one thing: if $AP$ is tangent to the circle and $P$ is on the circle, then $AP$ is perpendicular to $OP$. And that can only happen if $P$ is on the circle with diameter $AO$. Construct that circle. You might have 0,1, or 2 intersection with circle $O$. That means you can get 0,1, or 2 lines. (in the 1 intersection case, you need to construct a line through $A$ that is perpendicular to $O$)